# How to condense a data frame into two columns based of a specific column entry

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, reformatting

If I have a data set like follows

```
Rater1 10 a 

Rater2 12 b 

Rater2 5 c 

Rater1 7 d
```

How should I code R to shift the data into a format like in two columns

```
Rater1 Rater2

10     12

7      5

a      b

d      c
```

to that one

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split(df, df$Rater), \(d) c(d$v1,d$v2)))
```

Output:

```
  Rater1 Rater2
1     10     12
2      7      5
3      a      b
4      d      c
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(Rater = c("Rater1", "Rater2", "Rater2", "Rater1"
), v1 = c(10, 12, 5, 7), v2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your final dataframe has columns with both numbers and characters in them and since a column can only have one class all the number would turn to characters.

We can do this with the help of `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries. First we change the columns to character, get the data in long format, create a row number column to uniquely identify each row and finally get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Rater) %>%
  group_by(Rater) %>%
  mutate(name = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Rater, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-name)


# Rater1 Rater2
#  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 10     12    
#2 a      b     
#3 7      5     
#4 d      c
```